# apply text-decoration: line through to generated checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Im finishing up the last bit of a todo list app I am creating. Basically users generate todo tasks which show up on the screen along with a checkbox and trash can icon to the right of it. For the most part the app is working as it should. The last thing I need to do is have it that when a user clicks a checkbox, text-decoration:line through effect takes place and crosses out the corresponding list item. I used to have this working but I had to shift around some things so resizing the screen would look better. Now my old way wont work. Ill post some code and if anyone knows how I can get this working I would really appreciate it. Thanks everyone!

The input:checked + li css below is what was originally working before I had to rearrange the order of how list items were generated.

```
    ul {
text-align:right; /*This pushes the checkbox/trash can right while the <li> in the js file floats the todo text left*/
list-style-type:none;
padding-left:0px; /*Makes up for not having the bullet point spacing on smaller screens*/ 
font-size:24px;
color:white;
font-weight:600;
}
li {      
text-align:left;
}
input:checked + li {     /*<<<<<------This is what I was using before and it worked*/
  text-decoration:line-through;
}


.todo-item::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;  
}

.todo-item {
  text-align: right;
}

.todo-item .todo-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%; /*  you can increase the size */
  text-align: left;
  /* you can use this props if you don't want another line 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; */

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;"> 
            <div class="row justify-content-center"> <!--Input Box-->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> <!--Add Button-->
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-right:15px; margin-top:30px;">
                    <button id="add" style="border-radius:50%; font-size:35px; width:65px;" class="btn btn-danger">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container text" style="display:inline-block;"> <!--ToDos-->
            <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-8">
                    <div id="todos"></div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript used to develop items for the todo list. Prior to rearranging, the checkbox was generated before the todo list item. Now, it was shifted to after. I thought I could just rearrange my css order or perhaps take out the li section and replace it with a class. I havent had much luck here.

```
function show() {
var todos = get_todos();

var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li class="todo-item">' + 
      '<span class="todo-label">' + todos[i] + '</span>' +
      '<input class="checkBox" type="checkbox">' +
      '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">' + 
      '<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + 
      '</button>' +
  '</li>';
};
html += '</ul>';    
document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
};
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way of adding the line-through effect when the checkbox is clicked and removing the effect when the checkbox is unclicked is using the toggle method to toggle a premade class with the line-through effect. This class should not be on by default because you don't want the line-through effect right away. When you click the checkbox, it will toggle the class on. When you unclick the checkbox, it will toggle the class off.

HTML should be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li> Todo Item <input .....> </li>
```

Then create a CSS class for your code to toggle:

```
.lineThrough {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

The jQuery code would look like this:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("lineThrough");
});
```